# Uniform and Pointwise convergence of $\{f_n(x)\}$ where $f_n(x) = x^n \cos(2\pi xn)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ where $f_n(x) = x^n \cos(2\pi xn)$ and $x \in [0,1]$

What is the point-wise limit $g(x)$ of the sequence?

Does the sequence converge uniformly to $g(x)$?

I think I have it with $g(x) = 0$ and yes, the sequence converges uniformly. I would just like to check since I'm a little unfamiliar with these concepts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

does not converge uniformly since at $x=1$, $f_n\to 1$. (and elsewhere $f_n\to 0$ as you said)